# 'RECEIVE TOP(X) ' and services

Tags: sql-server-2008, service-broker

When sending messages with SSB we'll initialize conversations by specifying *to* and *from* services.

But when reading, all we do is to RECEIVE without specifying services. So how do I make sure that I read messages which are only for service X?

Or have I missed something fundemental?

Answer (score 1):

To RECEIVE for service A, RECEIVE from service A's queue. To RECEIVE from service B, RECEIVE from service B's queue.

You should only place two services on the same queue if the processing is identical and you really do not care about which service does the message belong to. You can even project the service name in the RECEIVE result set so you can know that your message belongs to A or B, if is important in processing. As a general rule there is no way to declare 'RECEIVE messages that meet criteria X and ignore the rest'. The idea is that messages are *events* that require handling, so you cannot choose what event you look at next.